# Is it possible to override Html.RenderAction() in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, renderaction

I want to send/pass some data as parameter from one `.cshtml` to another `.cshtml` page.

For example: `Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controler", new{name="ABC", age=23});`

https://domain/Controller/Action

[.cshtml page]

```
<label>Name: <label><label>@name<label><br />
<label>Age: <label><label>@age<label><br />
```

Comment: Yes, you could, but you probably don't want to. What have you tried? Why do you want this? Why don't you use partials or display templates?

Comment: I need to pass custom variable name with custom value as shown in the example.